# how to handle the visibility of the ItemizedOverlay in mapview in android?

Tags: android, visibility, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay, android-maps

i want set the visibility to itemized overlay in map view. if the zoom level is less than 10 i want to set visibility of overlay is GONE else VISIBLE. how to do that?  and also cant set zoom level Listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want set the visibility to itemized
>   overlay in map view. if the zoom level
>   is less than 10 i want to set
>   visibility of overlay is GONE else
>   VISIBLE.

Overlays do not have a visibility. If you do not want the overlay to appear, remove it from the `MapView`'s list of overlays.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class based on ItemizedOverlay, add a field to  like `m_isVisible' and override the draw function like;

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    if(m_isVisible){
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    }
}
```